# set Foreground color of element inside Selected Row of DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGridTemplateColumn defined as below. I need to change the Foreground property of both textblocks to White if the row is selected

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="User" Width="240" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,3,0,0" Foreground="#1c72c7" >
                        <Run Text="{Binding FullName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </TextBlock>
                <Label Padding="0,0,0,0"  Margin="0,0,0,3">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#1c72c7"  Margin="10,0,0,0" TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                </Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I already have a RowStyle defined to change the background color of the row as follows

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}" />
    </Style.Resources>

</Style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should modify the `Style` for each individual `TextBlock`, and add the behavior as you'd like, as so:

```
 <Style x:Key="FirstTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, 
             RelativeSource= {RelativeSource 
                                AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" 
             Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Comment: Apologies, while you are correct, both textblocks should have a different color (other than the default of black) when not selected. I've updated the xaml to be clear

Comment: @user48408: then you should modify the individual `Style` of `TextBlock`, and do it the same way as I've done, but instead use `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource=RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type typeOfAncestor}}}">...</DataTrigger>`.